# Eligibility for the competition?

Tags: support

I notice in the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-contest/) that to be eligible for the comp you need to be listed in the App tab. What is the criteria to get listed on that tab? [My app](https://stackapps.com/questions/924/a-stack-of-twits-tweeting-all-over-your-stack) is tagged correctly and I think I am using the correct format. Is it votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be in the apps tab, you must have enough votes.  Currently you must have at least 5 votes in order to be on the tab.

But, you are correct, this Question is tagged correctly.

Comment: Hmmm... believe it or not, I never knew about the 5 vote minimum.  Good spotting.

Comment: Hmmm... it has five votes now and it's not there.

Comment: Ah it seems that the app tab has a maximum number of questions, sorted by votes. So there must be lots of apps on 5 votes. Thankfully I now have 6 votes and I am on the list. Yay!