# AND searching for tags?

Tags: feature-request, api, documentation

I am using the search api to search for questions that are tagged with "tags" and not with "tags". However I have noticed that searching for tags is an OR search.

The questions search for tags is an AND search. Why the difference?

e.g.
AND Search
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/questions?tagged=php;mysql
OR Search
http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/search?tagged=php;mysql

Also would it be possible to switch the searching type from OR to AND on the search api by an option?

Comment: "tagged with questions and not with questions" typo?

Comment: your question is not comprehensible. could you specify which path(s) you are referring to and example urls.

Comment: Sorry folks, early morning etc...better now?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `questions` allows you to be more exclusive with your filter while `search` allows you to be more inclusive with your filter.

this flexibility is a good thing and, right now, I would not like to see it changed.

Comment: But you can't filter out questions that contain certain tags when searching using the question api call. I am also looking for flexibility, the ideal would be able to turn the search from an OR to and AND with an optional flag.

Comment: @john - you may have a point. i will give this some more thought when i get a few quiet moments.